# Subtracting dataframes with unequal numbers of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 4)), index=list('ABCDE'), columns=list('abcd'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(2, 4)), index=list('CE'), columns=list('abcd'))

   a  b  c  d
A  5  0  3  3
B  7  9  3  5
C  2  4  7  6
D  8  8  1  6
E  7  7  8  1

   a  b  c  d
C  5  9  8  9
E  4  3  0  3
```

The index of `df2` is always a subset of the index of `df1` and the column names are identical.

I want to create a third dataframe `df3 = df1 - df2`. If one does that, one obtains

```
     a    b    c    d
A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
B  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
C -3.0 -5.0 -1.0 -3.0
D  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
E  3.0  4.0  8.0 -2.0
```

I don't want the `NAs` in the ouput but the respective values of `df1`. Is there a smart way of using e.g. `fillna` with the values of `df1` in the rows not contained in `df2`?

A workaround would be to do the subtract only the required rows like:

```
sub_ind = df2.index
df3 = df1.copy()
df3.loc[sub_ind, :] = df1.loc[sub_ind, :] - df2.loc[sub_ind, :]
```

which gives me the desired output

```
   a  b  c  d
A  5  0  3  3
B  7  9  3  5
C -3 -5 -1 -3
D  8  8  1  6
E  3  4  8 -2
```

but maybe there is a more straightforward way of achieving this?

Comment: What's wrong with `df1-df2`? Isn't that your desired output?

Comment: No, I don't want the NAs there but the values of df1; I update the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `sub` method instead of `-`, you can pass a fill value:

```
df1.sub(df2, fill_value=0)
Out: 
     a    b    c    d
A  5.0  0.0  3.0  3.0
B  7.0  9.0  3.0  5.0
C -3.0 -5.0 -1.0 -3.0
D  8.0  8.0  1.0  6.0
E  3.0  4.0  8.0 -2.0
```

Comment: Works great, thanks (upvoted)! Any idea whether `sub` is more efficient than using `df1-df2` as in @not_a_robot's answer?

Comment: Did a quick testing and seems your solution is far faster.

Comment: Yeah, I also didn't test it on a large dataset but for small ones this seems faster.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you want:

```
(df1-df2).fillna(df1)

Out[40]: 
     a    b    c    d
A  5.0  0.0  3.0  3.0
B  7.0  9.0  3.0  5.0
C -3.0 -5.0 -1.0 -3.0
D  8.0  8.0  1.0  6.0
E  3.0  4.0  8.0 -2.0
```

Just subtract the dataframes like you would normally, but "package" the result using parentheses and run the `pandas.DataFrame.fillna` method on the result. Or, a bit more verbosely:

```
diff = df1-df2
diff.fillna(df1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `reindex` and its `fill_value` parameter.  The main differences between this answer and @ayhan's answer are:

- You can control the fill value on only one of the dataframes or both
- This could be generalized to `reindex` over a custom union of the indices of `df1` and `df2`
- We have better control to preserve the `int` data type

---

```
df1 - df2.reindex(df1.index, fill_value=0)

   a  b  c  d
A  5  0  3  3
B  7  9  3  5
C -3 -5 -1 -3
D  8  8  1  6
E  3  4  8 -2
```

Comment: Nice (upvoted), that seems even faster than @ayhan's solution.